# Android: make a view visible in RecyclerView without calling notifyDataSetChanged()

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, picasso

I have building a gallery project. I am using `RecyclerView` to show all the images coming from server. I am using `Picasso` to load the images into the `Adapter`. Now I have an `Edit button` on top of the `RecyclerView`. If I click on the `Edit button` I want to show a `dismiss button` on every image available in the `Adapter`. To make the button visible in all the items I am calling `notifyDataSetChanged()` inside the Adapter after clicking the `Edit Button`.

Problem is if I call `notifyDataSetChanged()`, Picasso is loading all the images again. How can I avoid reloading of Images again ?

Comment: You can not avoid reloading of images because whenever you want to change in your recyclerview /listview then you have to notify your adapter to behave accordingly. You can do one thing to allow caching of images so images will load fast.

Comment: Yeah agree with @SurenderKumar, but you can cache your images too through your picasso setup to make it faster image to load.

Comment: Any better solution then caching ? @LesterL.

Comment: What will happen if I delete some image from the gallery ? if I reopen the app will Picasso load the image from cache ?

Comment: If you delete image from the gallery you can't load it anymore coz it's a reference to each other.

Comment: Why you don't want to load your images again ? It's local right ? It's fine to load and load and load your image again and again and again. coz it's local. Then when you are using RecyclerView that's the expected to do to load and load and load.

Comment: Images coming from server. @LesterL.

Comment: If its coming from the server then you need to setup your image processor like picasso to make it cache. It will load your images faster if images already load first time.

Answer (score 0):

you can hide the button by calling `button.setVisibility(View.GONE);`
and on clicking editbutton use `button.setVisibility(View.Visible);` to show button

Comment: but that too will require notifyDataSetChanged(); to be called to notify the changes in the list made.